# a man of mean stature (this mean stature man is short or average?)

Tags: phrase-meaning

> a man of mean stature

Does the 'mean' above mean short or middle? My dictionary says both of them and makes me being confused.

Comment: Where did you see this?

Comment: [correction: it confuses me] Is this from an 19th century novel?

Comment: Just a personal dictionary(I am Asian; Asians published the dictionary). @FumbleFingers You are so good at explanation and I take my hat off to you.

Comment: 1599 work about [sword] fencing: _Scholar: Who has the advantage in fight, of a tall man, or a man of mean stature? Master: The tall man has the vantage, for these causes: his reach being longer[etc]_,

Comment: Here are [all 3 occurrences of the collocation ***of mean*** in Dickens](http://www.online-literature.com/dickens/) (in 3 different books). Two refer to *houses*, the other to *robbers*. None have any implications of "average".

Comment: @FumbleFingers In math, 'mean' as a noun menas 'average'.

Comment: Have I written anything to suggest I'm unaware of that meaning? Note that there's scope for "interpretation" with @MichaelHarvey's cited  1599 example, but personally I take it for granted that ***mean*** there means ***lowly, insignificant [short]*** rather than ***average***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle, ***mean*** could carry either sense, but almost certainly the intended meaning is "short", not "average".

BUT in fact several written instances returned on [the first page of a Google Books search](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a%20man%20of%20mean%20stature%22) are from English/French phrase books where it's translated as *c'est un homme de moyenne stature*. My French may be a bit rusty, but I'm pretty sure the French version always means "average".

Also note that in English, this use of ***stature*** can be a metaphorical reference to ***standing / status** (in society)*, not literal ***height***.

---

If the source is a 19th century novel, note the relevant definition 3b in the full OED: *Petty, insignificant, unimportant; inconsiderable. Now **rare.*** It was often used that way in Victorian novels (by Dickens, for example), but you should avoid it yourself today.

Comment: OED says '6.A.6 Not far above or below the average; moderate, mediocre, middling. †a.A.6.a **Of or with reference to size, stature, or age**. Examples from 1364 to 1697, and later (1750s) Doctor Johnson defined 'of mean stature' as 'moderate without excess'. The best we can say is that someone of 'mean stature' is not outstandingly tall, but they are not necessarily outstandingly short.

Comment: But a big part of the reason for posting my answer is to say that *almost certainly* that's ***not*** the intended sense in OP's case. We can quote contrasting dictionary definitions all day, but at the *end* of the day (1) OP hasn't supplied the *full exact context*, so we get no clue from that, and (2) The *most* important part of my answer is in the first 7 words (it's potentially ambiguous).  Me, I automatically assume OED's 3b ***insignificant*** sense (also their definition 3d ***unimposing***) in the absence of further context ...

Comment: ...for example [*He was **a man of mean stature**, his rich robes covering a **small flabby body**. His short fingers...*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+man+of+mean+stature%22+%22small+flabby+body%22) These days, "mean stature" is likely to be essentially disparaging.

Comment: [Here's the chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=of+average+height%2Cof+mean+stature&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) showing that it was way back in 1850 when ***of average height*** became more common than ***of mean stature***.  Since then the "default" connotations for the latter have gradually shifted further and further towards ["short-arse"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/short-arse), imho.